# Did Pilate have a vision of Woland/Satan?

Tags: russian-language, master-and-margarita, mikhail-bulgakov

In "Master and Margarita", after hearing from Berlioz that Jesus was a fictional character, Woland starts to describe the meeting between procurator Pilate and prisoner Yeshua Ha-Notsri, saying that "he was there, hiding".

I always assumed that he indeed was somewhere in the background, but then I've found this fragment, that describes Pilate reaction, when shortly after deciding to let Yeshua go (well "imprisoning" him in procurator's mansion), he finds that Yeshua is also accused of questioning Cesar's rule:

> Pilate another parchment.
>        'What else is there? ' enquired Pilate and frowned.
>        Having  read the further evidence  a change  came over his  expression.
>   Whether it  was blood flowing back into his neck and  face or from something
>   else that  occurred,  his skin changed from yellow to red-brown and his eyes
>   appeared to collapse. Probably caused by the increased blood-pressure in his
>   temples, something happened to the Procurator's  sight. **He seemed to see the
>   prisoner's head vanish  and  another appear in  its place,  bald and crowned
>   with a spiked golden diadem. The skin  of the forehead was split by a round,
>   livid  scar  smeared  with  ointment.  A  sunken,  toothless  mouth  with  a
>   capricious, pendulous lower  lip.** Pilate had  the  sensation  that the pink
>   columns of his balcony  and the roofscape of Jerusalem below and  beyond the
>   garden had all vanished, drowned in the thick foliage of cypress groves. His
>   hearing, too,  was  strangely  affected--there  was a  sound  as of  distant
>   trumpets,  muted and threatening, and  a nasal voice could clearly be  heard
>   arrogantly intoning the words: ' The law pertaining to high treason . . .'

Is that supposed to be a vision of dead Yeshua (but then "golden diadem"?), the ascension of Yeshua-as-Jesus (but then I've never heard about mutilated Jesus described as "toothless") or maybe it is Woland/Satan that Pilate sees?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but I had to reject your tag excerpt edit suggestion as it contained a definition rather than guidance. You're most welcome to propose it as tag wiki, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Canonical interpretation is that it was a vision of [Tiberius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiberius) - roman emperor of that time. One of the reliable sources for this is the [Gasparov's](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) [text](https://shakko.wordpress.com/2016/05/01/%D0%B1-%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD/) of about the structure of the novel, but no one argues with this interpretation.

And, as usual for Bulgakov, it also could be the reference to some real person from Bulgakov's time. Gasparov (and others) cautiously suggest that it could be a reference to Lenin. Some clues:

- "Crowned head" is the head of the empire ruler.
- Tiberius wasn't bald, but Lenin was. By the way in Russian text Bulgakov uses the word "плешивый", that means exactly "almost bald", "going bald". It's not the same as "completely bald" which is "лысый".
- Also lost in translation, Bulgakov writes about "капрейские сады" meaning "gardens of [Capri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capri)" (in your text they became "cypress groves"). That could be a reference to the meetings between [Maxim Gorky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxim_Gorky) and Lenin on Capri. (Meaning that Bulgakov's Pilate is Gorky, Gasparov elborates more on this topic).
- Further in  the novel there are Pilate's words to Tiberius. Gasparov assumes it is hidden quote from [Mayakovsky's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Mayakovsky) poem where the poet speaks about Lenin.
- Tiberius is the name related to [Tiber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiber), Lenin is the name related to [Lena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lena_River), also river.

Comment: > "That could be a reference to the meetings between Maxim Gorky and Lenin on Capri."

It could be. But please remember that Tiberius was the emperor who spent his last years in Capri, where he (already) had a number of villas (and supposedly gardens, too) //Wikipedia. I would say this rather reinforces the vision Pilates had as that of Tiberius.